# How to determine what node.js is waiting on to finish execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, apn-node

I have integrated a library which I am using that is causing my node.js application to remain running for an additional ~30 seconds after a simple operation. Is there a way to query and find out what callback this is waiting for? Even being able to set a breakpoint after the 30 seconds so I can see what did get called last would be very useful. I am debugging it in WebStorm.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector for debugging.